# Can I assume that it is always possible to open a pdf NULL device in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

For various functions in my cowplot package, I need to be able to convert ggplot2 plots into grobs, via the `ggplotGrob()` function. A known problem in this context is that `ggplotGrob()` requires an open graphics device, and depending on the graphics device currently open the call to this function creates a spurious empty plot. For examples of this problem, see [ggplot2 issue #809](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/809) or most recently [cowplot issue #82](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/82).

It is possible to fix the problem by opening a null pdf device. See the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make a plot
p <- qplot(1:10, 1:10)

pdf(NULL) # open NULL pdf device to absorb empty page
grob <- ggplotGrob(p) # convert plot
dev.off()
```

Now here is my question: Is the sequence `pdf(NULL); ggplotGrob(...); dev.off()` safe to use in an R package, or are there scenarios where I cannot assume that `pdf(NULL)` will be successful/possible? If such scenarios exist, are there other graphics devices I can assume exist, and can I test when I'm in a situation where `pdf(NULL)` would not be a good idea? Alternatively, what would be the best way to make the code tolerant to potential failure of the `pdf(NULL)` call?

Update: See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012518/why-does-this-r-ggplot2-code-bring-up-a-blank-display-device) which discusses the problem of blank pages but doesn't go into much detail of what safe methods there may be to work around the problem.

Update 2: [This comment](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/pull/72#issue-250568701) states that some R installs don't have a functioning `pdf()`. So it seems that it is indeed not always possible to open a pdf NULL device. The question then is: How can I work around this problem?

Comment: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16378

Comment: Thanks @baptiste! I assume you encounter similar issues in the `egg` library. What do you do? Use `pdf(NULL)` and hope for the best?

Comment: to be honest I've given up on this issue, like many others that were closed or dismissed. This sounds like a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this briefly when you first posted it. As "pdf" is not in `capabilities()`, it "should" always work. Or so one hopes. And I tried a to construct a counter example without X11 access---and hence no font metrics---but failed.

Now, I still see two work-arounds that should always help you:

1. Use the virtual framebuffer device in your R call; this is eg how we run the reverse depends checks "head-less". The call becomes something like [this set of lines](https://github.com/RcppCore/rcpp-logs/blob/73abf8c1e944353eff9ec27c242f2550c02cce32/scripts/runRcppDepends.r#L181-L184):

   xvfb-run-safe --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" R CMD ...whatyouneed...
2. Just say no to `pdf()` and use `cairo()` instead which is a) known to work headlessly and b) provided by two different packages.

Comment: Dirk, thanks for your answer. Had you seen [this comment,](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/pull/72#issue-250568701) which states that some R installs don't have a functioning `pdf()`? I think the `cairo()` solution is a no-go, because it creates an additional dependency for my package.

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Sure, there will be _some_ R installations with something or other broken as people do the darndest things to their systems.  The question is: is this systematic?  Would your unit tests break?  Would it fail at CRAN?  And I don't think, but maybe I am biased and spoiled as the systems we set up are sound and working ...